# Windows 10 black screen - no cursor - no safe mode - can't get in to change video driver

Tags: windows, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, black-screen-of-death

Windows 10 upgrade from Win 7 Ultimate finished & rebooted into low res. But it did work. Tried to upgrade video drivers to latest 2 versions of Win 10 Nvidia drivers. Both failed. EVGA GTX 970 SSC. Rebooted & after logo, came to black screen & stops.

Before upgrade, I should have changed video driver to generic low res version but forgot & left it on the Win 7 Nvidia driver which was NOT listed as Win 10 compliant (I discovered afterwards)

Tried HDMI Out from Nvidia card; Fail

Removed Nvidia card, selected MB Intel graphics in BIOS & connected to MB Video Out; Fail

Tried my Ultimate Boot CD. All attempts crash to blue screen. BUT..... next Win 10 boot, goes to failed startup screen & displays Advanced Repair oOtions;

STARTUP REPAIR: Fail.
REBOOT TO SAFE MODE: Fail
ENABLE LOW RES VIDEO: Fail
COMMAND PROMPT: Success   I can get the dos prompt & can see files & directories but that's it.

At one point, got this error: "System Thread Exception Not Handled - wdf01000.sys"

NTBTLOG.TXT shows dxkrnl.sys is the last driver to attempt loading before the black screen; it fails to load even though higher up the list it shows it did load.

So I guess I need to remove Nvidia drivers or know where to go to change the video driver to a plain jane basic generic driver; but I have to do it from DOS.

Anyone know the locations & filenames to do the job?

MB - ASUS Gene V Maximus   BIOS version-1903

CPU - Intel I5-3570k

RAM - 16 GB Crucial (2x8 GB)

Videocard - EVGA GTX 970 SSC

KB - Logitech G11

Mouse - Logitech Gaming Mouse.

Sound - Realtek built-in the MB.

Thanks

Comment: Your problem isn't  wdf01000.sys but a driver before it that is corrupting the memory.  If you cannot repair windows, boot into safe mode, then you don't have very many options except to reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: Any idea which driver may causing the problem?

Comment: Not possible without more information

Comment: Checked the ntbtlog.txt. Results;   AichargerPlus.sys failed to load 4 times but failed.             dxgkrnl.sys failed to load 3 times. It was the last driver on the list and it failed to load. BUT, way up the list, dxgkrnl.sys did load successfully, followed by Basicdisplay.sys (it loaded), then dxgkrnl.sys tried to load again & this was it's first failure.

Comment: If you can try manually loading each driver skip the aicharger, that particular driver , should NEVER be used

Comment: I never selected that Asus USB charger support to be loaded in BIOS. Not sure why it loads the driver.  I thought I would locate the aichargerPlus.sys file & rename it. I'll try that next. But being that it fails to load, that probably wouldn't work. Don't remember how to manually load drivers. Seems like there used to be a way to confirm each step of the startup sequence one at a time. Any ideas?     Thanks.

Comment: Also, when I get into thenAdvanced Repair Options & get a DOS Prompt, it shows I'm on drive X: in the Windows directory. The C: drive says it's reserved. And my old C: drive with Win 7 & all my old files & programs shows as drive E:.  If that means anything.   Thanks.l

Comment: OK. Tried renaming AiChargerPlus.sys & restarting: same failed start result. Changed filename back.  Being that I got into Windows 10 the first time it rebooted after the upgrade, I'm thinking of trying; "Reset the PC - Keep or remove your files & then reinstalls Windows". Then when I get back into Win 10 after the first reboot, I'll uninstall all Asus fluff programs & if my Nvidia drivers still won't install, I'll select a plain low res VGA video driver. Then try rebooting. Sound like a good idea?    Thanks

Comment: I only regonzied that driver as being the caused of my inability to load my camera in the desktop skype program.  Check out my struggles on that one ;-)

Comment: Tried the "Reset my PC & reinstall Windows 10 - keep my files". It failed & said it couldn't do it. I saved an image of my Win 7 setuo before the update to an external 1 TB drive that connects via USB. What's the quickest way to reimage my HD from that backup image?

Comment: try pressing FN + f6
hope that helps

Comment: How would Fn + F6 solve a problem which is most probably caused because of driver

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for a similar problem:

**Situation**:
I'm using the latest drivers for Windows 10 (353.62).
After Windows gets some updates, it needs to reboot; after the restart and the Windows startup logo, the screen remains black. System Repair doesn't help.

Relevant parts of my setup:

- Asus Sabertooth 990FX R2.0
- AMD FX9590 (8 core 4.7GHz)
- 32GB RAM
- GeForce GTX 960
- 2 Samsung UHD screens connected with DisplayPort cable
- 1 Samsung smart TV (on the wall) connected with HDMI cable
- Windows 10

**The solution:**
The workaround is surprisingly simple. Before starting the PC, the HDMI cable needs to be pulled out! Once logged in, the cable can be reconnected.

Before the Windows updates, the workaround was not necessary. We'll need to wait for a fix from Microsoft or nVidia, but until then, pulling the cable works.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I also ran into a driver issue which caused no video output (blackscreen even without any HDMI monitor plugged in. Also it happened on a MSI laptop, so don't tell me to unplug the video graphic card...

Windows wil try to detect boot failures : after 2 unsuccessful boot/login attempts, it will automatically bring up the recovery panel (not using the driver, so it should work). Here go to Troubleshoot > advanced setting > Startup setting > Restart with Safe boot (should be sthing like press F4)

Then hurry to go to the device manager from where you can uninstall your driver.

Now you can restart your computer and hopefully you can see something in normal mode. Make sre you download the latest drivers from the manufacturer, instead of garbage drivers you can find on the provided CD/Driver partition

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I undertook two successive hard, failed startups (interrupted startup with power button) and got into safe mode automatically. There I could install the latest drivers and sort the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I know from several forums, quite a few people are running into the same issue when upgrading from Windows 7 and 8 to Windows 10.  Many people are encountering a black screen.  If you have a black screen with a cursor, I understand from the forums that hitting control and then entering your login password may work.  Unfortunately, this did not work for me, and I had a complete black screen with no cursor.  After much headaches and fears of a massive re-installation, I think I came up with a super simple Fix to black screen with no cursor in Windows 10 after installation. 
After installing Windows 10 upgrading from Windows 7, I encountered a black screen with no cursor.  I couldn’t find my emergency boot disc, and I was too lazy to make a new one, and I couldn’t access anything on startup.  After trying several long reboots and encountering the same blank black screen, I tried 3 hard shut-off and restarts of my machine in a row quickly without allowing the computer to do a full reboot.  From what I understand, this is normally suppose to bring up Windows Recovery mode.  To my surprise, Windows 10 started right up!  No need to adjust any graphics settings or anything.

Comment: Please consider rewording your answer to actually provide an a succinct answer to the original question.